# Indentation in algorithmic package

Tags: algorithmicx, algorithmic

I have a renamed command in the algorithmic package:

```
\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm,algorithmicx}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Launch:}}
```

I like the way it looks, not having a number and no indentation.

However, I came up with anew case on where I would like to have some indentation on the line (while still not having a line number).

I have tried adding `\hspace`, but that does only add spaces *after* the **Launch:**, not before. How can I indent that line?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm,algorithmicx}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Launch:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{End Kernel}}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require{stuff 1} % this is OK
\For{for}
\State{loremIpsum()}
\Require{Unindented stuff 2}  % This is what I want to indent to the same level as the previous line

\State{loremIpsum} % indent also, but I can \qquad
\Ensure{} %  This is what I want to indent also

\EndFor
\Ensure{} % this is OK also
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a full compilable code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a version that should give the wanted result (if I understood the requirements correctly).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm,algorithmicx}

\makeatletter
\def\ALG@special@indent{%
    \ifdim\ALG@thistlm=0pt\relax
        \hskip-\leftmargin
    \else
        \hskip\ALG@thistlm
    \fi
}
\newcommand{\Launch}[1]{\item[]\noindent\ALG@special@indent \textbf{Launch:}\ #1}
\newcommand{\EndKernel}{\item[]\noindent\ALG@special@indent \textbf{End Kernel}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Launch{stuff 1}
\For{for}
  \State{loremIpsum()}
  \Launch{Unindented stuff 2}
  \State{loremIpsum}
  \EndKernel
\EndFor
\EndKernel
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

I added new commands `\Launch` and `\EndKernel` to make the code more readable, as I assume you just used the other names because the output looked somewhat similar to what you want.

Both commands just insert simple lines without line numbers (like `\Statex`), but take some special care about the indentation. If one of these commands occurs at the top-level, no indentation is added; if it occurs somewhere inside another block, the current block indentation is used.